# Jfrog pipelines throws an error duing sync after step type is updated

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I created a pipeline source (by following the [Jfrog pipeline developer docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipelines+Steps) for steps) which had a step of type jenkins

```
- name: firstStep
    type: Jenkins
```

I synced my pipeline source and the sync was successful

Later I updated the step type to be a bash step

```
- name: firstStep
    type: bash
```

After this change, the pipeline sync fails with the error below:

```
type cannot be updated from Jenkins to Bash in step firstStep
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a step is created and synced successfully, the type of that step cannot be changed.
This is not supported. Please refer the document: [JFrog Pipeline Steps](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipelines+Steps) for more information

If you still want the step type to be `Bash` then may be you can rename the step name, it will be added as a new step and the old step with name `firstStep` will be deleted.